# Change HTTP Response message

Tags: django, http

I am using http response to handle exception in my website. I want to show proper message / validation during create and update data. But It shows HTTP responses like Bad Request , Internel server error. Here is my code:

```
from django import http
from rest_framework import viewsets

class SaleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     data = request.data
     try:
       // Some code
        return http.JsonResponse(response)

    except Exception as e:
       logger.error(e)
       return http.HttpResponseBadRequest(content=e)
```

In dialog box message it shows ,"Bad Request". Instead of "Bad Request" in dialog box message I want to show custom message.

I want to do ,

```
 except Exception as e:
           logger.error(e)
           return http.HttpResponseBadRequest(My message)
```

Comment: Use https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response with proper status code instead

Comment: @iklinacc I am getting response if there is error, but i want to change that response message - Bad Request to custome message

Comment: Why not render out a custom page for errors, passing the  error message through context ?

Comment: @SANGEETHSUBRAMONIAM can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) object

create a custom error response handler

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def error_response(message, status, error=None):
    response = dict()
    response["error"] = error
    response["detail"] = message

    return JsonResponse(response, status=status)
```

in your views

```
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(e)
    # call custom error_response handler
    message = 'My message'
    return error_response(message=message, error=e, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```